# Running batch file using Shell with VB6 causes loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vb6

I have a bat file that checks if UAC admin is required, if so, prompts UAC and then copies some dll files:

```
@echo off
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"

cd /d %~dp0
if /i "%PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER:~0,3%"=="X86" (
    echo system is x86
    copy .\*.dll %windir%\system32\
    regsvr32 /s /c %windir%\system32\filetoregister.dll
    ) else (
        echo system is x64
        copy .\*.dll %windir%\SysWOW64\
        regsvr32 /s /c %windir%\SysWOW64\filetoregister.dll
    )
```

This works fine when run from windows explorer, if UAC is required, it prompts etc, does exactly what I want, however, if I try to run the batch file from a VB6 programme thus:

```
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = App.Path & "\setup\install.bat"
ShellVal = Shell(FilePath, vbNormalFocus)
```

It works fine if UAC not required but if it is, it asks for permission, after selecting an admin account it then goes into a loop of opening and closing the cmd window. Shutting down the computer is often the only way to kill it

I have tried just using the UAC part of the bat file, still same problem

Really stuck on this one, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED
I sorted this problem by removing the admin request from the batch file and using ShellExecute in the 
VB6 programme to get admin rights (if required) and then run the batch file

```
Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = App.Path & "\setup\install.bat"
    ShellExecute 0, "runas", FilePath, Command & "/admin", vbNullString, SW_SHOWNORMAL
```